# ¿Como agregar el ultimo objeto agregado de un array en otro o que este acumule los objetos?

Tags: javascript

Hola mi idea es pasar solo el ultimo elemento insertado en mi array **carrito**  otro array, he logrado que se sobrescriba el objeto en el array `var carrito=[]//esta inicialido antes de esta funcion`

Lo que necesito:

- Agregar "`esta listo`"
- Dibuje en la tabla "`esta listo`"
- Acumule dicho elemento para posteriormente preguntar si se encuentra en la tabla, si cumple la condición devuelva "`ya se agregó`", si no "`no se agregó correctamente`".

```js
const newItem = {
    id: id,
    codigo: codigo,
    nombre: nombre,
    cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponible,
    talla: talla,
    talla_ropa: talla_ropa
}
carrito.push(newItem)
 
const temp = carrito[carrito.length - 1];
var nuevoArreglos = [];
```

Se añade el 1ero posición 0 si añado el 2do  el 2do pasa a la posición 1 y el que se añadió pase al 0 y así.

Comment: no tengo el ejemplo en concreto mi idea es añadir un solo objeto ala tabla dando el boton añadir, ejemplo si tengo 3 elemntos se añada ala tabla una sola vez quedando la tabla con 3 objetos solamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para añadir un elemento al final de un array, usa `push`:

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const el = 7;
arr1.push(el);
console.log(arr1); // [1, 2, 3, 7]
```

El último elemento añadido se encuentra entonces en la última posición, puedes recuperar este elemento:

```
const temp = arr1[arr1.length - 1];
```

y añadirlo a otro array, ya definido, usando la variable:

```
const arr2 = [];
arr2.push(temp);
```

o directamente:

```
const arr2 = [];
arr2.push(arr1[arr1.length - 1]);
```

*Obtenemos el último elemento del primer array en base a su longitud.*

Comment: como lo obtengo en base a sus elemntos

Comment: @FelipeBarros de la forma que te he indicado, se mide el numero de sus elementos y se recupera el que ocupa la última posición. En un array el primer elemento esta en la posición 0, siempre contamos desde 0, entonces el último elemento esta en la posición que equivale al número total de elementos menos 1.

Comment: sisisi entendido, pero como hacer que se valan añadiendo al array2, porque hasta el momento me sobreescribe el dato

Comment: @FelipeBarros, no entiendo bien que quieres decir, pero viendo tu código, creo que quieres rellenar el nuevo array con las IDs de los objectos del primer array, pon la línea `nuevoArreglos[i].push(newItem2)` dentro del `for`.

Comment: eso ya lo solucione, lo que necesito ahora es que en el 2do array se vayan acumulando,porque asi podre acumular los objetos y pintarlos 1 a 1 y luego preguntar si existen que eso ya lo tengo hecho lo de si existen o no

Comment: se añade el 1ero      posicion 0  si añado el 2do  el 2do pasa a la posicion 1 y el q se ñadio pase al 0 y asi

Comment: @FelipeBarros quitale `[i]` a `nuevoArreglos[i].push(newItem2)`

Comment: noose como hacerlo la verdad pense que esto lo sulocionaria pero no